# render youtube video with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, axios, youtube-data-api

my goal is to give the query to youtube search and render the retrieve videos in my simple react js application. I after `npm start` for this react component, nothing comes up in localhost. in console I have just this error continuously, I used axios to fetch the data from API:

```
Yutube.js:23 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

here is my YoutubeRitriver react JS component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class YouTube extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {video: []};
}

componentWillMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.VideoList();
    }, 2000)
}
VideoList() {
    axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key={MY DATA GOOGLE KEY')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({video: response.headers});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
            <div className="panel-list">
                {this.state.video.map((item, i) =>{
                    return(
                        <h1>{item.items}</h1>

                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: A 400 error is a bad request. Try looking for the details of the error in the request inside the network tab in the browser console. It should give you a hint about where you messed up the request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to handle your VideoList method as middleware for asynchronous action, bz you excute it in ComponentWillMount, event your interval timer will never be reached, as react suggestion stop using ComponentWillMount, you can try your asynchronous action in ComponentDidMount but we will see for a better answer :-) ..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the URL you provide to fetch as you are getting a 400 http status back.

> 400 BAD REQUEST
>   The server cannot or will not process the request due
>   to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed
>   request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

Source: [*httpstatuses*](https://httpstatuses.com/400)

Your axios call should be as following (specifically check the `key=` part)
`axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key=[your-api-key]')`

Replace `[your-api-key]` with your API-key.

You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to check your call and make sure it works. It also gives insight into the data that is returned. From what I can see, you set state with the following `this.setState({video: response.headers});`

When I check the results from the fetch. I receive a json object with the following structure.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/ipQV3_cO6U60ZQAQFbmLuvvwHsI\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
      "totalResults": 171,
      "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
      {
          "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
          "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/qKI5Yg1Vl2i2-2N6r0fbQoupdS0\"",
          "id": "VVViVzE4SlpSZ2tvX21PR201ZXI4WXpnLlRId1hfbEUtbElJ",
          "snippet": {
              "publishedAt": "2018-01-30T09:35:59.000Z",
              "channelId": "UCbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg",
              "title": "One Direction - One Way or Another (Teenage Kicks) (Live at the BRIT Awards 2013)",
              "description": "One Direction - One Way Or Another (Teenage Kicks) live from The BRIT Awards 2013.\n\nStream more music from One Direction here: http://smarturl.it/OneDSpotify \n\nMore from One Direction:\nDrag Me Down: https://youtu.be/Jwgf3wmiA04 \nPerfect: https://youtu.be/Ho32Oh6b4jc \nHistory: https://youtu.be/yjmp8CoZBIo \nNight Changes: https://youtu.be/syFZfO_wfMQ \nSteal My Girl: https://youtu.be/UpsKGvPjAgw \nKiss You: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4cdfRohhcg  \nYou & I: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kqQDCxRCzM   \nStory of My Life: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-TE_Ys4iwM  \n\nFollow One Direction:\nFacebook https://www.facebook.com/onedirectionmusic/   \nTwitter https://twitter.com/onedirection  \nInstagram https://www.instagram.com/onedirection/   \n\nMore great videos here http://smarturl.it/1DVevoX  \n\nSubscribe to One Direction on YouTube: http://smarturl.it/1DYT\n\nhttp://vevo.ly/YkR6Yy",
              "thumbnails": {},
              "channelTitle": "OneDirectionVEVO",
              "playlistId": "UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg",
              "position": 0,
              "resourceId": {
                  "kind": "youtube#video",
                  "videoId": "THwX_lE-lII"
              }
          }
      }, {
        // next item
      }, {
        // another item
      }
    ]
}
```

Make sure you assign items to state properly. It will likely look like this.
`this.setState({video: response.data.items});`

Then, when mapping over it, use the following to display the title for example. `this.state.video.map((item, i) => <h1 key={i}>{item.snippet.title}<h1>)`.